# Difficulty showing Cochran's theorem for the chi-squared distribution due to dependence of variables

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\p}{\operatorname{Pr}}\newcommand{\pdf}{\operatorname{pdf}}\newcommand{\cdf}{\operatorname{cdf}}\newcommand{\n}{\mathcal{N}}$Suppose we have a sequence of $n$ standard normal variables $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^n$ which are i.i.d: I want to show that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(X_k-\bar{X})^2\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$$

First, I use these formulae, which can be derived by differentiating the $\cdf$ for *independent* variables:

$$\pdf_{X^2}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\pdf_X(\sqrt{x})-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\pdf_X(-\sqrt{x})&x\gt 0\\0&x\le 0\end{cases}\\\pdf_{X+Y}(x)=(\pdf_X\ast\pdf_Y)(x)\\\pdf_{\alpha X}(x)=\frac{1}{|\alpha|}\pdf_X(x/\alpha)$$

Now I expand the sum, which is a random variable I'll call $S$:

$$S=\color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^nX^2_k}\color{green}{-\frac{1}{n}\left(\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^nX_k}\right)^2}$$

The red, green and blue random variables I'll call $A,B,C$.

I show that $A$ is distributed according to $\chi^2_n$:

> First let us check $n=1$, i.e. the distribution of a squared standard normal variable $X$. According to the formula, when $x\gt0$: $$\pdf_X^2(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\pdf_X(x)-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\pdf_X(-\sqrt{x})=\frac{x^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\right)$$Which is the $\pdf$ of $\chi^2_1$ as expected. Now inductively assume that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k\sim\chi^2_n$, and consider $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}X_k^2$, where $X_k$ are again all standard normal variables. Using the addition formula, the $\pdf$ of the new sum will be the convolution between two $\chi^2$ distributions, as the additional $X_{n+1}^2$ was shown to follow $\chi^2_1$: $$\pdf_{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}X^2_k}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\pdf_{\chi^2_n}(t)\pdf_{\chi^2_1}(x-t)\d t$$But since the $\chi^2$ $\pdf$ is zero for negative values, the integral becomes $0$ for negative $x$, and for positive $x$ it becomes: $$\int_0^x\left(\frac{t^{n/2-1}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}t\right)}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}\right)\left(\frac{(x-t)^{-1/2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-t)\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)\d t$$Which can be simplified to: $$\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\right)}{2^{(n+1)/2}\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(1/2)}\int_0^xt^{n/2-1}(x-t)^{-1/2}\d t$$Under $u=t/x$, we find: $$\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\right)}{2^{(n+1)/2)}\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(1/2)}\int_0^1(ux)^{n/2-1}(x-ux)^{-1/2}(x\d u)=\frac{x^{(n+1)/2-1}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\right)}{2^{(n+1)/2)}\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(1/2)}\mathcal{B}\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$$Finally giving: $$\pdf_{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}X_k^2}(x)=\frac{x^{(n+1)/2-1}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\right)}{2^{(n+1)/2}\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(1/2)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma((n+1)/2)}=\pdf_{\chi^2_{n+1}}(x)$$Inductively therefore we are done, and the variable $A$ follows a $\chi^2_n$ distribution.

Now examine the blue variable, $C$:

> I will show inductively that: $$\pdf_{\sum_{k=1}^nX_k}(x)=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2n}x^2\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi\cdot n}}$$This is clearly true of $n=1$. Assume its truth for some $n$ and consider the case $n+1$; adding by convolution gives: $$\begin{align}\pdf_{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}X_k}(x)&=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi\cdot n}\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(t^2-2t\cdot x)-\frac{1}{2n}t^2\right)\d t\\&=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi\cdot n}\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\left(t^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{-1}t\cdot x\right)\right)\d t\\&=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi\cdot n}\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{n+1}{2n}\left(t^2-\frac{2n}{n+1}t\cdot x\right)\right)\d t\\&=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi\cdot n}\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{n+1}{2n}\left(t-\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot x\right)^2+\frac{n+1}{2n}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^2x^2\right)\d t\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\cdot n}\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\left(\frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}\right)x^2\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{n+1}{2n}t^2\right)\d t\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\cdot n}\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}x^2\right)\sqrt{\frac{2\pi\cdot n}{n+1}}\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(n+1)}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}x^2\right)\end{align}$$Inductively, we are done.

Now let's look at the green; $C^2$, which is then scaled by $-\frac{1}{n}$:

> Using the evenness of $C$, $$\pdf_{C^2}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\pdf_C(\sqrt{x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi nx}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2n}x\right)$$Scaling by $-\frac{1}{n}$ yields the green variable, $B$, to have $\pdf$, now only valid for *negative* $x$: $$\pdf_{B}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot|x|^{-1/2}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)\sim-\chi^2_1$$And the $\pdf$ is now $0$ for positive $x$.

Finally, $S$ has distribution equivalent to $A+B$, and so we convolve:

> $$\pdf_S(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\pdf_A(t)\pdf_B(x-t)\d t$$

But numerical evaluation suggests that this last integral is *not* the desired $\pdf$ for $\chi^2_{n-1}$. What's my mistake?

Note: I realise that $B$ is simply the negative of a $\chi^2_1$ variable, and I *could* try to argue that since $\chi^2_{n-1}+\chi^2_1\sim\chi^2_n$, then $\chi^2_n-\chi^2_1\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$. However, I believe that this is not true, since the subtraction of two independent normal variables yields the same as the addition, and the variables are independent, right? Maybe the solution is that since $A,B$ both depend on $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^n$, they are *not* independent so the convolution formula doesn't hold, and indeed I can make the seemingly naive subtraction of $\chi^2_n-\chi^2_1\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$

Comment: The convolution formula $$ f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\,\mathrm{d}X$$ holds only when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, continuous random variables. However, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k^2$ and $\overline{X}^2$ are *not* independent.

Comment: @SangchulLee I have just come to a similar conclusion - see my note at the bottom. Is the issue resolved by the realisation that $A,B$ are not independent?

Comment: I didn't check if the computations of other parts are correct or not, but based on my knowledge they seem fine. So I believe the incorrect application of the convolution formula is the very source of the issue.

Comment: @SangchulLee What's the addition of *de*pendent variables, do you know? Does it depend upon the nature of their dependence? I have just started a brief burst of interest in probability theory, which will shortly end, and I am not a probability student at all. I have little intuition here!

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ is jointly continuous with the joint PDF $f_{X,Y}$, then $$f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)\,\mathrm{d}x. $$ However, this leaves the question of determining the joint distribution. In your problem, I believe that it is easier to directly adhere to the gaussian structure of the underlying random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first note that, if $\mathbf{1} = (1, \ldots, 1)$ and $\mathrm{X} = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ are regarded as column vectors, then $S$ is a quadratic form in $X$:

$$
S
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} (X_k - \overline{X})^2
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k^2 - \frac{1}{n} (X^{\mathsf{T}} \mathbf{1})(\mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}} X)
= X^{\mathsf{T}} P X,
$$

where $P = I_n - \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement $\operatorname{span}(\mathbf{1})^{\perp}$. So, the moment generating function of $S$ is given by

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[e^{\lambda S}]
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{\lambda x^{\mathsf{T}}Px} \frac{e^{-|x|^2/2}}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}  \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-x^{\mathsf{T}}\left( \frac{1}{2}I_n - \lambda P \right)x} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Now if $\Sigma$ is an $n\times n$ positive-definite matrix, then it is well-known that

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-x^{\mathsf{T}}\Sigma x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\det \Sigma}}. $$

Since the eigenvalues of $\frac{1}{2}I_n - \lambda P$ are $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}-\lambda, \ldots, \frac{1}{2}-\lambda$, it follows that $\frac{1}{2}I_n - \lambda P$ is positive-definite for $\lambda < \frac{1}{2}$ and

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[e^{\lambda S}]
&= \frac{1}{2^{n/2}\sqrt{\det\left( \frac{1}{2}I_n - \lambda P \right)}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det\left( I_n - 2 \lambda P \right)}}
= \frac{1}{(1-2\lambda)^{(n-1)/2}}.
\end{align*}

This is precisely the m.g.f. of $\chi^2_{n-1}$, and therefore $S \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$.

Comment: Ah, twice now I have asked a statistical calculus question and received an answer in terms of linear algebra - so much simpler! I have one quibble: what is the relevance of $P$ being an orthogonal projection? You say “So”, but I don’t get the point there - if there is one. I intuitively understand why the MGF of S is this way - you have replaced the expected value integral $\int_{\Bbb R}x f(x)dx$ with $\int_{\Bbb R^n}p(X) f(S)dx$, loosely speaking, but formally I can’t quite see how they are the same. I’m expecting the integral to look like: $$\int_{\Bbb R^n}\mathbf{x}e^{\lambda P(S)}d\bf x$$

Comment: @FShrike, That $P$ is an orthogonal projection allows us to discuss the positive-definiteness of the matrix $I_n-2\lambda P$ as well as easily compute its eigenvalues. Also, from [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), for any continuous random vector $X$ and for any "nice" function $g$, you get $$\mathbf{E}[g(X)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g(x)f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ In our case, $g(x)=e^{\lambda x^{\mathsf{T}}Px}$ and $f_X(x)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}e^{-|x|^2/2}$. (The formula $\mathbf{E}[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is a very special case of LOTUS.)

Comment: I have studied more linear algebra than I have probability, so I’ll accept LOTUS, but I am quite curious as to what your eigenvalue trick was. Was it this: $$\begin{align}(I-2\lambda P)v&=tv\\Pv&=\frac{1-t}{2\lambda}v=\frac{1-t}{2\lambda}Pv\\\frac{t+2\lambda-1}{2\lambda}Pv&=0\end{align}$$Which implies $v\in\mathrm{span}{\bf 1}$ with $t=1$ and $t=1-2\lambda$ for all the other eigenvalues. Right?

Comment: @FShrike, Yes :) Also, LOTUS is intuitively appealing, because it tells that the expectation of $g(X)$ is merely the "weighted average" of the values $g(x)$, weighted by the probabilities of $X$. Measure-theoretically, it is more or less the change-of-variables formula.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting alternative method. I'm mostly writing this so that I can dump my thoughts now and write down notes later.

Through this post, $n$ is an integer greater than $1$ and $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ are i.i.d standard normal variables. We define $\overline{X}_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nX_j$. I want to show $(X_j-\overline{X}_n)_{j=1}^n$, as an $\Bbb R^n$-valued random variable, is independent of $\overline{X}_n$.

Define: $$\begin{align}\phi:\Bbb R^n&\to\Bbb R^n\\(a_1,\cdots,a_n)&\mapsto(a_1+a_n,a_2+a_n,\cdots,a_{n-1}+a_n,a_n-a_1-a_2-\cdots-a_{n-1})\end{align}$$This is a diffeomorphism with Jacobian: $$\mathrm{d}\phi\simeq\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&\cdots&0&1\\0&1&0&\cdots&0&1\\0&0&1&\cdots&0&1\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0& 0&0&\cdots&1&1\\-1&-1&-1&\cdots&-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$By induction we can show the determinant is $n$ - calculate the minors in the positions $(n-1,n-1)$ and $(n-1,n)$.

Notice that $\phi(X_1-\overline{X}_n,X_2-\overline{X}_n,\cdots,X_{n-1}-\overline{X}_n,\overline{X}_n)=(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ and the right hand side is a standard $n$-dimensional normal variable. It follows that $(X_1-\overline{X}_n,\cdots,X_{n-1}-\overline{X}_n)$ is distributed with the p.d.f: $$\begin{align}(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)&\mapsto\frac{n}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(a_j+a_n)^2+\left(a_n-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j\right)^2\right)\right)\\&=\cdots\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi/n}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a_n}{1/\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\right)\\&\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{n-1}/n}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j^2+\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j\right)^2\right)\right)\end{align}$$

Which is the product of the p.d.f of the standard normal distribution in the $n$th coordinate - the distribution of $\overline{X}_n$, the $n$th coordinate of the random variable - with some other function (necessarily the p.d.f of $(X_1-\overline{X}_n,\cdots,X_{n-1}-\overline{X}_n)$). It follows $\overline{X}_n$ is independent of $(X_1-\overline{X}_n,\cdots,X_{n-1}-\overline{X}_n)$ hence also independent of $(X_1-\overline{X}_n,\cdots,X_n-\overline{X}_n)$, as desired, since: $$X_n-\overline{X}_n=-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(X_j-\overline{X}_n)$$

---

Given this, Cochran's theorem is easy. Consider: $$\sum_{j=1}^n X_j^2=\left(\sqrt{n}\cdot\overline{X}_n\right)^2+\sum_{j=1}^n(X_j-\overline{X}_n)^2$$As a sum of *independent* random variables. The left hand side is $\chi^2_n$-distributed, the first summand on the right hand side is $\chi^2_1$-distributed. Taking characteristic functions, it follows easily that the second summand - $\sum_{j=1}^n(X_j-\overline{X}_n)^2$ - is $\chi^2_{n-1}$-distributed, as desired.